# Sending multiple instance forms to template - Django

Tags: python-3.x, django-forms

Hi Stack overflow people:

I would lithe to receive some orientation in this following newbie python Error

I have two model forms in my forms.py:

```
class StrategicDnaValuePropositionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = "Adn Estratégico y Propuesta de valor"

    class Meta:
        widgets = {
            'familiar_enterprise':forms.RadioSelect,
            'enterprise_concepts':forms.RadioSelect,
            'value_purpose_target':forms.RadioSelect,
            'competition_differentiation':forms.RadioSelect,
            'goals_objectives':forms.RadioSelect,
            'avoid_competition':forms.RadioSelect,
            'enterprise_strategy':forms.RadioSelect,
        }

        model = StrategicDnaValueProposition
        fields = ('familiar_enterprise', 'enterprise_size',
            'enterprise_concepts', 'value_purpose_target', 'competition_differentiation', 'goals_objectives',
            'avoid_competition')


class MarketingSalesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = "Mercadeo y Ventas"

    class Meta:
        widgets = {
            'key_activities':forms.RadioSelect,
            'new_clients_strategies':forms.RadioSelect,
        }

        model = MarketingSales
        fields = ('key_activities', 'new_clients_strategies',)
```

In my view, I would like to generate two forms instances of these model forms and send to the template to save them.

My views.py:

```
@login_required
def diagnostic_tool_questions(request):
    user = request.user

    # Populate the forms
    form_diagnostic = []

    if user.is_enterprise:
        profile = user.get_enterprise_profile()
        form_diagnostic.append({
            'form_strategicdna': StrategicDnaValuePropositionForm,
            'form_marketing_sales': MarketingSalesForm,
            'instance': user.enterpriseprofile,
        })

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # forms = [x['form'](data=request.POST,) for x in form_diagnostic]
        forms = [x['form'](data=request.POST, instance=x['instance'],) for x in form_diagnostic]
        if all([form.is_valid() for form in forms]):
            for form in forms:
                form.save()
            return redirect('dashboard')
    else:
        forms = [x['form'](instance=x['instance']) for x in form_diagnostic]
    return render(
        request, 'enterprise_process/strategicdnavalueproposition_form.html',
        {'forms':forms, 'userprofile':profile,})
```

My template is:

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}

{% block title_tag %}Herramienta de Diagnóstico | CRIMBLU {{ block.super }}{% endblock %}

{% block body_content %}
<div class="container">
    <h1>Account Details</h1>
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for form in forms %}
            {% bootstrap_form form %}
        {% endfor %}
        <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" class="btn btn-default">
    </form>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

When I go to the url which call to my diagnostic_tool_questions view I get the following message:

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
May 26, 2017 - 19:40:20
Django version 1.11, using settings 'consultancy.settings.development'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Internal Server Error: /herramienta-diagnostico/preguntas/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/consultancy_dev/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/consultancy_dev/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/consultancy_dev/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/consultancy_dev/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 23, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bgarcial/workspace/consultancy_project/enterprise_process/views.py", line 66, in diagnostic_tool_questions
    forms = [x['form'](instance=x['instance']) for x in form_diagnostic]
  File "/home/bgarcial/workspace/consultancy_project/enterprise_process/views.py", line 66, in <listcomp>
    forms = [x['form'](instance=x['instance']) for x in form_diagnostic]
KeyError: 'form'
[26/May/2017 19:40:23] "GET /herramienta-diagnostico/preguntas/ HTTP/1.1" 500 89072
```

Django tell me that I have some interprete error in the line:

```
else:
        forms = [x['form'](instance=x['instance']) for x in form_diagnostic]
```

The `KeyError: 'form'` I unknown the reason which appear ...
Excuse me by the newbie error.

Comment: Like what the traceback says, the key `'form'` didn't exist within you `x` dict's variable. Can you check for `x.keys()` ?

Comment: Excuse me, How to check `x.keys` I am not very familiarized with list comprehensions

Comment: `forms = [ x.keys() for x in form_dignostic] ` it will save the keys of the elements of the `iterable form_diagnostic` in the variable called `forms` and then check the keys of the dicts in your current iterable if the key `form` exist or not.

Comment: Can I check the keys in `forms` variable in my template? I add `x.keys` `Parameter "form" should contain a valid Django Form` ..

Comment: In fact, there is not some instance form in `forms` variables  althought the dictionary have them, but the keys dos not have

Comment: `form_diagnostic 
[{'form_marketing_sales': <class 'enterprise_process.forms.MarketingSalesForm'>,
  'form_strategicdna': <class 'enterprise_process.forms.StrategicDnaValuePropositionForm'>,
  'instance': <EnterpriseProfile: Luisa Fernanda Garcia Muriel>}]
forms 
[dict_keys(['form_marketing_sales', 'form_strategicdna', 'instance'])]
profile 
<EnterpriseProfile: Luisa Fernanda Garcia Muriel>
request 
<WSGIRequest: GET '/herramienta-diagnostico/preguntas/'>
user 
<SimpleLazyObject: <User: @luisa>>`

Comment: So, there isn't any key called `form`. You may reconsider your list comprehension in order to extract your desired data.